# Need help with exact solution and proof of well-posedness for linear first order IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Apologies for any mistakes or inefficiencies in my submission and wording of the question. It is my first time using stackexchange.

The IVP is as follows:

$u' = \cos(u(t))$, subject to the initial conditions $u(0) = 0$, where $0\le t\le 1$.

I separated the variables, solved for the general solution, and applied the initial conditions giving me the solution $u(t) = 2\arctan(e^{t + \log(\tan(\pi))}) - \frac{\pi}{2}$

According to wolfram alpha, however, the correct solution is $u(t) = 2\arctan(\tanh(\frac{t}{2}))$.

I would like to see where my error is as well as how to show well-posedeness of the problem. I have already shown the solution to exist and be unique, however, I don't quite know how to show that it's behaviour changes continuously with respect to the initial conditions(stability).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to find where your error is if you do not show your work. However, something is definitely wrong, since $\log(\tan\pi)$ is undefined.

Let's check now the well poshness. Let $u(x,a)$ be the solution with initial value $u(0)=a$. Then
\begin{align}
|u(x,a)-u(x,b)|&=\Bigl|a-b+\int_0^x\bigl(\cos(u(t,a))-\cos(u(t,b))\bigr)\,dt\Bigr|\\
&\le|a-b|+\int_0^x|\cos(u(t,a))-\cos(u(t,b))|\,dt\\
&\le|a-b|+\int_0^x|u(t,a)-u(t,b)|\,dt.
\end{align}
Now use Gronwall's inequality.